# successive "the" in connected words

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I am wondering if it is possible to use only a "the" at the beginning of some successive nouns instead of using "the" for all the nouns; by the way of illustration:

the system and law both contribute to governing equations;

instead of:

the system and the law both contribute to governing equations

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In general*, English gets by without repeating the article, as in "Put the eggs, milk and butter in a bowl".  But I'd say that it would be better to repeat it in the case of "the system and the law", because "the law" is an entity [standing e.g. for "the law of England and Wales"], different from "law" in general".

Comment: An obvious pair of sentences illustrating the 'single concept v two entities' difference: 'The bacon and eggs was delicious.' / 'The bacon and the eggs are both running out.'